# Report Incorrect Classifications

Tags: video-intelligence-api

What is the best way to report high confidence incorrect classifications from Google Video Intelligence API?

For example one of our submitted videos has a logo that is 87% confidence but misclassified as the wrong organization throughout a majority of the video.

Comment: I created a public issue tracker for the incorrect logo classification by the API. In the issue tracker you can add details like sample files and the full API response of the incorrect logo detection so it can be reproduced easily by the Video Intelligence Engineering team. See issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/197705856

Comment: Also if you have a support package you can file a ticket to report this issue.